# Cleaning string column that contains float number

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove the point and zero from every float value within this dataset

```
  index     CIP
    1        DF5TY34
    2        12342.0
    3        de44dW
```

(CIP is casted as String)

I wrote this line to resolve the problem but its not doing anything and I'm recieving only a warning no errors:

```
 pro1[pro1['CIP'].str.contains('\..')]["CIP"] = pro1.loc[pro1['CIP'].str.contains('\..')]["CIP"].astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)
```

this is the warning:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Comment: try this, `df['CIP'].str.rstrip('.0')`?

Comment: I think you did it! rstrip stands for right strip?

Comment: Yup, doc link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html

Comment: `rstrip('.0')` isn't good: it'd turn "170" into "17". Use `removesuffix('.0')`.

Comment: thank you niccolo i just discovered it right now doing some calculations! I really appreciate your help and time all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a strict replacement of `.0`, you can use [`removesuffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html):

```
df['CIP'] = df['CIP'].str.removesuffix('.0')
```

For a more flexible approach, use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['CIP'] = df['CIP'].str.replace('\.0*$', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
   index      CIP
0      1  DF5TY34
1      2    12342
2      3   de44dW
```

regex:

```
\.   # match a dot
0*   # match any number of 0 (including none)
$    # match end of line
```

Comment: The replace approach was the first i thought about but it replace all the string with an empty one so you will end up with NaN fields where the condition is true

Comment: I get this error for removesuffix

AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'removesuffix'

Comment: @Monta which version of pandas do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code if you want to convert the float value in string

```
pro1['CIP'] = pro1['CIP'].apply(lambda x: (str(int(x)) if isinstance(x, float) else x))
```

if you don't want to convert into  string - then remove  the str()

```
pro1['CIP'] = pro1['CIP'].apply(lambda x: (int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x))
```

for round off

```
pro1['CIP'] = pro1['CIP'].apply(lambda x: (round(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x))
```

You can do anything you want on float values by selecting in this way